# How does tomcat change in classloading behavior when it runs as services vs running standalone batch?

Tags: java, tomcat, jsoup, vaadin

I have the same issue as mentioned [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2736346/2736576).

Vaadin seems to work just fine when Tomcat runs as a service and mysteriously throws `NullPointerExcption` in intializing JSoup when tomcat is directly run from the batch file. This is an issue seen on Tomcat 7.

Is class loading different when Tomcat runs as service vs Tomcat running from batch file? I tried placing JSoup jar in `JRE_HOME/lib` and `CATALINA_HOME/lib`. The error remained the same.

Comment: Can you  post a stacktrace?

Comment: stacktrace is same as in the link.